# Select specific row from mysql table based on a column value

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I select an specific row from mysql table?

This is my table:
[image]

I want to select on a specific Token value, so what I tried is this:

`SELECT * FROM Oefeningen WHERE Token = ('a6rqc')`

But that returns me nothing, could somebody help me out on this?

Comment: Try where `token='a6rqc'` without the brackets? Alternatively, `where token in ('a6rqc')` should also work

Comment: Please verify if you don't have a space before or after the token in the Token cell.
Additionally, check if `WHERE Token LIKE 'a6rqc'` does the trick, or even `WHERE Token LIKE '%a6rqc%'`

Comment: Check whether there is any space at the end or beginning of the string

Comment: Good point. You can also do `where token like '%a6rqc%'`

Comment: There is not, every other column gets picked up for example: `SELECT * FROM `Oefeningen` WHERE Herhaling1 = 20` show me the result but for Token its not

Comment: So my suggestion does not help? The `%a6rqc%`?

Comment: @Henry that show me a result can you explain me why

Comment: @Sreinieren: In that example (1) you're not using parentheses and (2) you're using a numeric value instead of a string.  It doesn't change anything that's been suggested.

Comment: As people have said, you may have a space somewhere. Either leading or trailing. Using `%` means wildcard match, so `abca6rqczzz` would also give a match. But its a nice way to understand if you have space issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a trailing or leading space. I.e. the value might actually be `token=' a6rqc'` or it might be `token='a6rqc '`. If you use `%`, you will be able to wildcard match, i.e. `token like '%a6rqc%'`

Comment: But I want to target that specific perfect matched token not a wildcard match

Comment: @Sreinieren: Then you have to use that specific perfect matched value.  Which includes whitespace in your data.

Comment: Yes, but now you have learned that the problem is being caused by a space somewhere. You need to try to understand where it is caused (i.e. leading or trailing? Exactly how many?)

Comment: I found the issue when i push the token it is getting pushed with an space infornt

Comment: Ta-da ! :) See? Personally when I do string matching, I try to wildcard match every string. This is why people like UserIDs and similar.

Comment: Using `LIKE` with wildcards is poor advice.  If the known issue is leading whitespace, the script that is saving the values with leading whitespaces should be corrected, then the table column should be purified by running an UPDATE query leveraging `TRIM()`.  At the very worst, the SELECT clause in the question should be using `WHERE TRIM(\`Token\`) = 'a6rqc'` (https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-trim-function.php), but never `LIKE` because that could lead to incorrect results where one string is a substring of another.